# Multiple JOINs with same column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, multiple-columns

I have to select `id` from `GraphNodes` whereas same `id` exists in `GraphEdges` in two columns i.e. `Source_Node` and `Target_Node`. The structure of tables are as follows:

**GraphNodes**

```
+---+---------+-------------------+------------+-----------+
| id | Node_ID | Node             | Node_Label | Node_Type |
+---+---------+-------------------+------------+-----------+
| 1  |  677    | Nuno Vasconcelos | Author     |    1      |
| 2  |  1359   | Peng Shi         | Author     |    1      |
| 3  |  6242   | Z. Q. Shi        | Author     |    1      |
+----+---------+------------------+------------+-----------+
```

**GraphEdges**

```
+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+------+-----------+
|Source_Node | Source_Node_Type | Target_Node | Target_Node_Type | Year | Edge_Type |
+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+------+-----------+
| 1          |  1               |  10965      |     2            | 2005 |   1       |
| 1          |  1               |  10179      |     2            | 2007 |   1       |
| 1          |  1               |  10965      |     2            | 2007 |   1       |
+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+------+-----------+
```

I have shown only 3 rows for both tables just to get an idea of table's structures. I have used query as:

```
SELECT GN.id as Node_ID, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(GE.Source_Node, '-', GE.Target_Node))) 
       AS Mutual_Links -- OR Node_Degree
FROM GraphEdges GE
JOIN GraphNodes GN ON GN.id = GE.Source_Node --How to JOIN this
                  AND GN.id = GE.Target_Node --How to JOIN this
WHERE (Source_Node IN (SELECT id FROM GraphNodes 
                       WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 510) 
                       AND Edge_Type IN (1, 2, 3))
OR (Target_Node IN (SELECT id FROM GraphNodes 
                    WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 510) 
                    AND Edge_Type IN (1, 2, 3))
GROUP BY GN.id
```

I want output in the form:

```
+--------+-------------+
|Node_ID | Mutual_Links|
+--------+-------------+
|  1     | 31          |
|  2     | 23          |
|  3     | 12          |
| ...    | ...         |
+--------+-------------+
```

The issue is that how to join `GraphEdges` with `GraphNodes` that I can get `id` OR  `Node_ID` form `GraphNodes` and COUNT DISTINCT Mutual_Links from `GraphEdges`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this

```
;with thedata ( id, MutualLinks ) 
as (Select id, MutualLinks = count(*) from [dbo].[GraphNodes]
inner join [dbo].[GraphEdges] on Source_node = node_id
group by id 
union all
Select id, MutualLinks = count(*)   from [dbo].[GraphNodes]
inner join [dbo].[GraphEdges] on target_node = node_id
group by id )
Select id, total = sum(MutualLinks)
from thedata
group by id
```

Comment: @Cameront--can't get what this query is doing?

Comment: It should work though? It is seeing the Source and Target as 2 separate result sets which I merge together via the UNION statement. I use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to merge them together as a single query result set and then we sum them together. The CTE acts like a temporary table in this case.

Comment: @Cameront--it is not giving desired results

Comment: @Cameront--can we have a chat?  I have came up with another solution in form a query want to discuss ?

Comment: OK. You can send me the details of how you have solved it if you like.