# Passing parameters to query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, parameter-passing, multiple-columns

I have to count edges between neighbors of nodes in a graph in SQL Server whereas I have tables as `GraphNodes` and `GraphEdges`. The structure of tables is available in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650353/multiple-joins-with-same-column-sql-server)

Relating to previous question, here is the aspect of question is different as:
I have to execute these steps to perform the task i.e.

1. take a node say **V** from `GraphNodes`
2. have to have `DISTINCT`
       neighbors list for **V** (e.g. in a **TABLE** variable SQL)
3. check (COUNT DISTINCT) links between neighbors of **V** in
   `GraphEdges`
4. output **V** with DISTINCT links between its neighbors

The query I have tried for a single node works fine i.e.

```
SELECT GN.id, COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(GE.Source_Node,'-', GE.Target_Node))) AS NeighborLinks
FROM GraphEdges GE
JOIN GraphNodes GN ON GN.id = 512
WHERE Source_Node IN (SELECT DISTINCT Target_Node FROM GraphEdges WHERE Source_Node = 512
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT DISTINCT Source_Node FROM GraphEdges WHERE Target_Node = 512
                     ) 
  AND Target_Node IN (SELECT DISTINCT Target_Node FROM GraphEdges WHERE Source_Node = 512
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT DISTINCT Source_Node FROM GraphEdges WHERE Target_Node = 512
                     )
GROUP BY GN.id
```

I have taken id = 512 as a sample where it is `id` in `GraphNodes`. This query outputs as:

```
+-------+-----------------+
|  id   |   NeighborLinks |
+-------+-----------------+
|  512  |   6             |
+-------+-----------------+
```

The reason for using `UNION ALL` in `WHERE` clause is that the `id` i.e. `512` exists in both columns i.e. `Source_Node` and `Target_Node` as well, so have to select DISTINCT neighbors from both columns is necessary. Moreover, using same list for `GE.Source_Node` and `GE.Target_Node` because have to check links only between neighbors of **V** i.e. `512`.
The question is how to use what I think the TABLE variable or any other method to sort out this problem of providing long list of values instead of `512`

I have came up with this solution regarding table variable but got error using table variables inside query as:
**Try 1**

```
DECLARE @ID TABLE(id INT)
DECLARE @S_Neighbor TABLE (id INT)
DECLARE @T_Neighbor TABLE (id INT)

INSERT INTO @ID SELECT id FROM GraphNodes

INSERT INTO @S_Neighbor SELECT DISTINCT Source_Node 
                        FROM GraphEdges 
                        WHERE Target_Node IN (SELECT id FROM @ID)
--UNION ALL
INSERT INTO @T_Neighbor SELECT DISTINCT Target_Node 
                        FROM GraphEdges 
                        WHERE Source_Node IN (SELECT id FROM @ID)

SELECT GN.id,COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(GE.Source_Node,'-', GE.Target_Node))) AS Mutual_Links
FROM GraphEdges GE
JOIN GraphNodes GN ON GN.id = @ID
WHERE Source_Node IN (SELECT DISTINCT Target_Node 
                      FROM GraphEdges 
                      WHERE Source_Node IN @T_Neighbor

                      UNION ALL

                      SELECT DISTINCT Source_Node 
                      FROM GraphEdges 
                      WHERE Target_Node IN @S_Neighbor)
   AND Target_Node IN (SELECT DISTINCT Target_Node 
                       FROM GraphEdges 
                       WHERE Source_Node IN @S_Neighbor

                       UNION ALL

                       SELECT DISTINCT Source_Node 
                       FROM GraphEdges 
                       WHERE Target_Node IN @T_Neighbor)
GROUP BY GN.id
```

I also tried this:
**Try 2**

```
DECLARE @ID_COUNTER INT
DECLARE @MAX_ID INT

SET @ID_COUNTER = 1
SET @MAX_ID = 148410

WHILE @ID_COUNTER <= @MAX_ID
BEGIN
  (
    SELECT GN.id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(GE.Source_Node,'-', GE.Target_Node))) AS Mutual_Links
    FROM GraphEdges GE
    JOIN GraphNodes GN ON GN.id = @ID_COUNTER
    WHERE Source_Node IN (SELECT DISTINCT Target_Node 
                          FROM GraphEdges WHERE Source_Node = @ID_COUNTER
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT DISTINCT Source_Node 
                          FROM GraphEdges WHERE Target_Node = @ID_COUNTER
                         ) 
       AND Target_Node IN (SELECT DISTINCT Target_Node 
                           FROM GraphEdges WHERE Source_Node = @ID_COUNTER
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT DISTINCT Source_Node 
                           FROM GraphEdges WHERE Target_Node = @ID_COUNTER
                          )
    GROUP BY GN.id
   )
  SET @ID_COUNTER += 1
END
```

I have used @MAX_ID = 3 and it took 56 sec to return output whereas @MAX_ID is originally = 148410. Though the returned values for `NeighborLinks` are correct but the output shown is in three separate windows for as:

```
id  NeighborLinks
1   53
```

---

```
 id NeighborLinks
 2  318
```

---

```
id  NeighborLinks
3   297
```

---

Comment: ...you wrote all this to ask how to pass list of int values as a parameter?

Comment: You are already suggesting a table variable yourself. What is keeping you from using table variables? An alternative would be to use a temporary table for storing the id's.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Not all yeah, but its a two fold issue, one is how to store and pass int values as parameter repeatedly and other is how to JOIN same column twice

Comment: @TT. I have tried table variable but unable to sort out

Comment: Show us the error message and the line which it corresponds to. Most likely, instead of `WHERE Source_Node IN @T_Neighbor` you should write `WHERE Source_Node IN (SELECT ID FROM @T_Neighbor AS TN)`. `JOIN GraphNodes GN ON GN.id = @ID` is also wrong and it is completely unclear to me what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov The goal is defined in four steps in question what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like the snippet below.

I've created a temporary table for the graph nodes (`#graph_edges`). The nodes for which you want to look up the number of (distinct) neighbors is in temporary table `#nodes`.

```
CREATE TABLE #graph_edges(source_node INT NOT NULL,target_node INT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE #nodes(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
--INSERT INTO #nodes(id)VALUES(512),(513),(514); -- specific nodes to look up in the graph
INSERT INTO #nodes(id)
SELECT source_node FROM #graph_edges UNION SELECT target_node FROM #graph_edges; -- lookup for all distinct nodes ID's in the graph


SELECT id,neighbor_links=COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT n.id,l=ge.source_node,r=ge.target_node
        FROM #nodes AS n
             INNER JOIN #graph_edges AS ge ON
                 ge.source_node=n.id
        UNION -- union of the two sets, this filters duplicate rows (ie no duplicate source_node,target_node row will appear in the derived table)
        SELECT n.id,l=ge.target_node,r=ge.source_node
        FROM #nodes AS n
             INNER JOIN #graph_edges AS ge ON
                 ge.target_node=n.id
    ) AS l
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;

DROP TABLE #nodes;
DROP TABLE #graph_edges;
```

Comment: @TT.--I have executed your answer but it returns `0` rows as you are INSERTING the VALUES INTO #nodes manually ?

Comment: @Taufel Did you substitute `#graph_nodes` with your `GraphNodes` table in the script? The results will be zero if there are no nodes in the graph.

Comment: @TT.--I think there is not entry in script as `#graph_nodes`

Comment: @Taufel I meant to say `#graph_edges` with `GraphEdges`.

Comment: @TT.--As you have created these tables right above the script that's why I didn't disturbed your script and also you have dropped at end as these were temporary tables? And what `INSERT INTO #nodes(id)VALUES(512),(513),(514);` this means? Just 3 values ?

Comment: @Taufel Your question is a bit unclear, but I thought you asked how do I look up the number of neighbor links for more than just one node ID? Well, the temporary table `#nodes` contains the node ID's for which you want to look up the number of neighbor nodes. I've added three values to show you how to add those node ID's to the "lookup" table, the parameter as you call it in your question.

Comment: @TT.--So do we have to add all those values manually i.e. 148410 in number

Comment: @Taufel What node ID's do you want to look up? Do you want to look all node ID's that appear in the graph? Do you want to look up only specific node ID's, eg ID's that are supplied by a user in the program? Another source perhaps?

Comment: @TT.--I want to look up all node ID's in graph whereas graphNodes has 148410 ID's and graphEdges has 534897 edges between those ID's. The #ToDo task is defined in four steps in question

Comment: @Taufel I've added something to the script to populate the `#nodes` table (nodes to look up) with all node ID's present in the graph. For better help in the future, please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) on *"How to post a T-SQL question on a forum"*. You should include table definitions, a sample set of data, and the required output.

Comment: @TT.--I have supplied table definitions in a link i.e. `previous question` in this question and required output is also provided. The issue with the sample data is it's much bulk data, and providing just data sample will not help in constructing the query as table structures also depicting the data form

Comment: @TT.--Please let me know what more you need to help out, I'll surely provide it as it is